# Bell number, equivalent.

Tags: equivalence-relations, bell-numbers

The $n$-th Bell number $B_n$ can be defined by $\displaystyle e^{e^x-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{B_n}{n!}x^n$ or $\displaystyle B_n=\frac 1e\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{k^n}{k!}$ or $\displaystyle B_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nkB_k$. My question : when $n\longrightarrow +\infty$, find a simple equivalent for $B_n$, and how to prove it. Thank you.

Comment: See http://dlmf.nist.gov/26.7.iv

Comment: I missed the asymptotics given by Vaclav Kotesovec in 2015. It also involves Lambert function.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I believe de Bruijn's is the simplest. He also gave a complete expansion in his classical book.

Comment: @Gary. Thanks for that. I have the vague memory that Philippe Flajolet also worked this problem. Am I correct ?

Comment: Thank you. It seems to me that in de Bruinj's we find $\displaystyle B_n\sim e^{n\ln(n)-n\ln(\ln(n))-n+...}$ but I don't see how to get an equivalent.

Comment: Have a look at https://oeis.org/A000110/a000110_4.pdf

Comment: Thank you. I have the feeling that due to the exponential term no simple equivalent can be written.

Comment: @P.Fazioli On page 107 of de Bruijn's book, formula (6.2.6) gives the proper asymptotics for $B_n$. The simplification for the logarithm comes afterwards.

Comment: Thank you. I would be very grateful if someone could to complete the following : $\displaystyle B_n\underset{{n}\rightarrow{+\infty}}\sim ...$ (in the sense that quotient has limit $1$), with equivalent function of $n$ only, using "usual" fonctions ($n^n,a^n,\ln^2(n)...$). It seems to me that de Bruijn's book page 107-108 raises a serious issue for doing that.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation of sequence $A000110 $ in $OEIS$, there a superb approximation proposed by Benoit Cloitre in $2002$. It write
$$B_n \sim b^n e^{b-n-\frac{1}{2}} \sqrt{\frac{b}{b+n}}$$ where
$$b\log(b)=n-\frac 12 \implies b=\frac{2 n-1}{2 W\left(\frac{1}{2} (2 n-1)\right)}$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.

To give you an idea, I computed the logarithms of both for $n=10^k$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 0 & 0.00693073010 & 0\\
 1 & 11.6606419521 & 11.6611299296 \\
 2 & 266.357984292 & 266.357226410 \\
 3 & 4438.17691251 & 4438.17671459 \\
 4 & 63699.1791462 & 63699.1791119
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Oh, wonderful approximation, much better than simple equivalent since up to $o(1)$ apparently. Where can I find a proof of this if it has been proven ? Thank you.

Comment: @P.Fazioli.  The OEIS page contains so much documentation ! Moreover, de Bruinj's approximation is probably more than sufficient. If you accept curve fit as an approximation ... Let me know.

Comment: Thank you. It is actually not so hard to find asymptotics for $\ln(B_n)$ and in particular $\displaystyle \ln(B_n)\underset{{n}\rightarrow{+\infty}}\sim n\ln(n)$. But $\displaystyle B_n\underset{{n}\rightarrow{+\infty}}\sim ??$. I don't manage to see in OEIS or elsewhere if this question has been answered.